# Is there any node.js IDE for OS X that prints out json objects like Chrome/Firefox console do?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, macos, ide

So, when I `console.log(object)` in Google Chrome, a traversable view of that object is printed out in the console, not just a string representation.

It's really, really handy.

However, when I run node.js scripts on my mac via `CodeRunner` or `WebStorm`, this doesn't happen.

Is there any node.js IDE for OS X that does that?

Answer (score -1):

[Atom](https://atom.io) seems to do what you require - give it a shot. :)

[image]

Comment: hey, ty @lizardspoc. I just installed Atom, but it seems to be only an editor, without the possibility of running the code (e.g. node script). Should I install some additional package to do that?

Comment: Atom is highly extensible using either the UI or their package manager (apm) via the cli.

Comment: You could use [node-debugger](https://atom.io/packages/node-debugger) to debug your code.

Comment: I set atom up, but it doesn't show json as you said it would ;(